# change creation date of parent folder as well as all child objects

Tags: powershell

I am running a script to change the creation date of files/folders however although it changes the folders and files within a folder it does not change the date of the actual parent folder. the script is below, could anyone advise what needs changed.

```
# Get the files
$gFiles = Get-ChildItem -recurse G:\
# Loop through them all
$gFiles | ForEach-Object {
    # Set the creation date without returning any output
    ($_.CreationTime = '10/08/2014 1:00') |Out-Null
    # Test if the previous operation was successful:
    if($?)
    {
        # Success, create an object containing the Path and status
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            "FilePath" = $_.FullName
            "Result"   = "Success"
        }
    }
    else
     {
        # Success, create an object containing the Path and status
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            "FilePath" = $_.FullName
            "Result"   = "Failed"
        }
    }
# Export the objects containing the result to a .CSV file
} |Export-Csv -LiteralPath "C:\pslog.csv" -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to include as `Get-ChildItem` only enums the child filesysteminfos.

Something like this -

```
$gFiles = (Get-ChildItem -recurse G:\) + (Get-Item G:\)
```

Comment: i have tried again but still the same issue. my script now looks like the following however I have only incuded the fisrt 2 lines as the rest is identical to above.                                                                # Get the files
$gFiles = Get-ChildItem -recurse G:\ + Get-Item g:\